# ModX: getPage extra is not working correctly with different access permissions on resources

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am working on a website built with ModX. I have defined different user access permissions for different resources. On a page I am trying to list down all the resources with pagination using `getPage` plugin. But I am not getting the list paginated properly. It seems like `getPage` is also considering inaccessible resources while paginating. Can anyone help me on this? Please!

Answer (score 1):

You don't write too much about what you did, but I suspect that you used resource groups and restricted the access to  the groups in the web content for some users. If you restrict access to a group at one place, modx doesn't allow anyone without *explicit* rights to access resources from that group.

To allow anonymous users to view your resources, don't restrict access to that resource group in the web context for anyone.

If you need more information, you might read over the [excellent tutorial on modX revolution permissions](http://bobsguides.com/revolution-permissions.html) by Bob Ray or the [pages on security in the modx manual](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Security).

Please provide further information on your problem, if this doesn't help (i.e. is it possible to access your desired resources without being logged in?).